# List question in Python

Tags: python, list, exception

Alright, so I have a list of 296 data points and four blank spaces. I cannot edit this list of data points. i have another list of 300 data points. I want to multiply the lists together, with python skipping multiplying the data points when a blank space shows up. Here's what the lists look like:

```
a = [[6], [7], [], [7]]
b = [[100], [200], [300], [400]]
```

What sort of exception handling would I have to put in? My current code uses

```
for items in mathList:
  try:
      sumlist = [x * y for x,y in zip(grearp, rex)]
  except:
      print 'No data for',items
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is the length of both lists actually 300 then, with 0's or blank strings for the missing data points?  If so, this should come close:

```
newList = [x[0] * y[0] if x else None for x, y in zip(l1, l2)]
```

-- Edited --

I realized I didn't review the sample data quite as well as I could've.  As the inner list is empty it'll fail a truth test on its own, so just `if x`.  Also, added indexing for the inner lists on x, y.

Comment: This won't work as he has lists of lists, not lists of integers.

Comment: It's okay, I just removed the minilists and this worked. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @miles82 -> you're correct.  I've modified the code slightly.  In point of fact though, sometimes it's about demonstrating an approach more than it is providing a copy/paste solution.  The question boils down to "how do I conditionally operate within a list comprehensions" which both versions of my code demonstrate.

Comment: @Tim - Happy to help!  I'm glad it made sense.  :)

Answer (score 0):

Think that you can also use something like this(code below will prepare lists to be the same size and then calculates '*' if both values present - otherwise include the only value exist):

```
from itertools import izip_longest

a = [[6], [7], [], [7]]
b = [[100], [200], [300], [400]]

newList = [[x[0] * y[0]] if x and y else (x or y) for x,y in izip_longest(a,b, fillvalue=[])]
```